# I accidentally kept my vehicle Choke ON while riding?

Tags: engine, honda, scooter

I have Honda Dio 2015 Model. Yesterday, I kept the Choke ON while riding. I wanted to know what are the damages it probably causes to the engine? Does it have any after effects on the engine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will not damage the engine at all. All that will happen is that it will run richer, thus using more fuel.

If you did it for thousands of miles you'd probably end up with more deposits in the engine/exhaust, but even that is easy to sort.

Comment: And maybe more deposits on the sparkplugs?

Comment: Yep - I'd suggest that is included in 'engine'

Comment: Good point. Though I tend to stress these as item since that used to be my where I had problems in the past. (With a  Vespa moped which ran way too richt and whose plugs needed cleaning every few months. Still the principle should be the same.).

Comment: I left my choke on whilst riding a 125cc bike and within minutes it had overheated and slowly lost power until it died, with bluish smoke coming off the engine casing

Comment: My bike didn't start on 3 occasions because of fuel deposits on the spark plug (a local mechanic cleaned the spark plug and the bike started) and the authorized service center advised a change of spark plug, engine oil, drain cock packing, gasket cylinder head cov, gasket exhaust pipe, tube fuel, engine head cleaning, carb calibration and new o-rings. Turned out to be quite expensive. Is all of this justified or are they fleecing customers?

Answer (score 3):

The 'worst case scenario' that I can think of is this.  Your spark plugs become fouled because the motor ran too rich and the bike doesn't start.  You would need to remove the spark plugs and clean them with a carb or brake cleaner and re-install them.  Don't worry about your vehicle.  It's fine.

Comment: Even if the spark plug is fouled and I somehow manage to start the bike and switch off the choke, will a 10 minute ride on the bike be enough to consume the fuel that covered the spark plug? Or does the fuel just remain there and can be removed only by cleaning the spark plug?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a mixture richening device (rather than just a fast idle circuit used on most modern fuel injected vehicles), then fouled plugs, carbon build up (including on the lambda probe and cat), etc, would follow.

But a possibly bigger problem is washing the oil from the bores, greatly increasing engine cylinder wear, and some fuel getting past the rings to dilute the oil.

Of these the only one I would really worry about from a short 1 off ride would be the spark  plugs and a quick thrash ("Italian Tune Up") will probably clean those out.